# PHP curl_exec returns both HTTP/1.1 100 Continue and HTTP/1.1 200 OK separated by space

Tags: php, web-services, curl, http-headers

I'm calling a service from PHP using cURL, like this:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

and the request/response headers look something like this:

Request:

```
POST /item/save HTTP/1.1
Host: services.mydomain.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 429
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 06 Jul 2012 08:37:01 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Length: 256
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

followed by the body (json encoded data).

The problem is that the common thing is to split headers and body in the response by the first empty line encountered, except in this case, the empty line is after the `100 Continue` and therefore everything else gets pushed into the body–and that is not valid json anymore :-)

So my question is this: What's the common way to deal with this?
I have 3 options lined up:

1. Specify that curl should not expect `100-continue`? (How?)
2. Specify that curl should only send back the headers of the last response? (How?)
3. Manually check for `100 Continue` headers and disregard them and their following empty line? (In that case, are there other similar things that could happen, that I should manually check for?)

Unless I'm missing something obvious, I'm sure people have stumbled upon this and solved it many times!

Comment: Are you setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0)` and letting curl separate the response body from the headers for you?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté No, I am separating them manually. If I let curl separate the headers from the body, is there still a way to inspect the headers?

Comment: You can get the headers _sent_ using `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT`; however, you wouldn't be able to get the headers received aside from specific ones like the last response code, the content-type, content-length, and perhaps a few others. So if you need all of the response headers, the best option would probably be to use `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD)` or `CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE` and separate the body from the headers yourself.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté The Content-Type would be nice to have. Let's see if someone manages to create an answer with code using CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I will opt for #1.
You can force curl to send empty "Expect" header, by adding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:"));
```

to your code

If you want check it manually, you should define your own header callback and maybe write callback (look for CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION and CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION in [curl_setopt doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)), which has simply to ignore all "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue" headers.

Comment: Could removing the `Expect` header incidentally have any other consequences on the request/response http dialog?

Comment: @jgivoni If there is a possibility of declining of the  request (i.e. by webservice), there is a risk. Purpose of "100 - Continue" is to pre-validate POST request before sending the whole body (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html). If there is no risk of declining (or it is relatively small), you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: I'm selecting this answer because it fits with my particular need. Calling a webservice I have control over myself, there is no risk of declining the request.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another method that uses the approach I described in the comment by parsing the response into header vs. body using `CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE`:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://test/curl_test.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
// sets multipart/form-data content-type
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  'field1' => 'foo',
  'field2' => 'bar'
));

$data = curl_exec($ch);

// if you want the headers sent by CURL
$sentHeaders = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
$headerSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
curl_close($ch);

$header = substr($data, 0, $headerSize);
$body = substr($data, $headerSize);
echo "==Sent Headers==\n$sentHeaders\n==End Sent Headers==\n";
echo "==Response Headers==\n$headers\n==End Response Headers==\n";
echo "==Response Body==\n$body\n==End Body==";
```

I've tested this, and it results in the following output:

```
==Sent Headers==
POST /curl_test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: test
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 242
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------
d86ac263ce1b

==End Sent Headers==

==Response Headers==
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 06 Jul 2012 14:21:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) PHP/5.4.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4
Content-Length: 112
Content-Type: text/plain

==End Response Headers==

==Response Body==
**FORM DATA**
array(2) {
  ["field1"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  ["field2"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
**END FORM DATA**
==End Body==
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem but this solution does note work for me, finaly i have found this methode and all its fine:

we have to prepare data post fields before sending them:

```
function curl_custom_postfields($curl, array $assoc = array(), array $files = array()) {
/**
* For safe multipart POST request for PHP5.3 ~ PHP 5.4.
* @param resource $ch cURL resource
* @param array $assoc "name => value"
* @param array $files "name => path"
* @return bool
*/
// invalid characters for "name" and "filename"
static $disallow = array("\0", "\"", "\r", "\n");
// build normal parameters
foreach ($assoc as $key => $value) {
    $key = str_replace($disallow, "_", $key);
    $body[] = implode("\r\n", array(
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{$key}\"",
        "",
        filter_var($value), 
    ));
}
// build file parameters
foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
    switch (true) {
        case false === $value = realpath(filter_var($value)):
        case !is_file($value):
        case !is_readable($value):
            continue; // or return false, throw new InvalidArgumentException
    }
    $data = file_get_contents($value);
    $value = call_user_func("end", explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $value));
    $key = str_replace($disallow, "_", $key);
    $value = str_replace($disallow, "_", $value);
    $body[] = implode("\r\n", array(
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{$key}\"; filename=\"{$value}\"",
        "Content-Type: application/octet-stream",
        "",
        $data, 
    ));
}

// generate safe boundary 
do {
    $boundary = "---------------------" . md5(mt_rand() . microtime());
} while (preg_grep("/{$boundary}/", $body));

// add boundary for each parameters
array_walk($body, function (&$part) use ($boundary) {
    $part = "--{$boundary}\r\n{$part}";
});

// add final boundary
$body[] = "--{$boundary}--";
$body[] = "";

// set options
return @curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_POST       => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => implode("\r\n", $body),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Expect: 100-continue",
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary={$boundary}", // change Content-Type
    ),
));}
```

you have to prepare two arrays:
1- post field with normal data: (name1 = val1, name2 = val2, ...)
2- post field with file data: (name_file 1, path_file1, name_file2 = path_file2, ..)

and finaly call this function before executing curl like this.
$r = curl_custom_postfields($curl, $post, $postfields_files);

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this with 100s and 302s etc it's annoying but sometimes needed (gdata calls etc) so i would say leave curl returning all headers and extract the body a little differently.

I handle it like this (can't find my actual code but you'll get the idea):

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$headers = array();
$body = array();

foreach(explode("\n\n", $response) as $frag){
  if(preg_match('/^HTTP\/[0-9\.]+ [0-9]+/', $frag)){
    $headers[] = $frag;
  }else{
    $body[] = $frag;
  }
}

echo implode("\n\n", $headers);
echo implode("\n\n", $body);
```

I begrudge the longwinded hackish method (would prefer it if curl marked the body content somehow) but it has worked well over the years. let us know how you get on.

Comment: This won't work, because html response contains `\r\n` and not `\n`.

Comment: with "\r\n\r\n" it works for me ! seems to be all about : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63894 and seems to be corrected but on Ubuntu 14.04 up to date, I still have this bug ... annoying !