# Google Cloud Storage: Upload Object is returning HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

Tags: php, http, curl, google-cloud-storage

I'm noticing that, since July 29 2013, The GCS webservice has started returning "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue" instead of the usual "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"(followed by some metadata about the server).

This is seen when doing a PUT Object on my end.

My question is, how do I resolve this? Do I just re-send the request? Do I re-direct the request to another location?

---

here is what my request looks like:

```
    $headers = array('Host: '.$bucket.'.commondatastorage.googleapis.com',
                    'Date: '.$timestamp, $version_header, 'Content-Type: text/plain',
                    $project_header, 'Content-Length: '.filesize($objectPath),
                    'Authorization: OAuth '.$accessToken);

    $c   = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($objectPath)); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); //timeout in 60s
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($c);
```

---

Comment: Are you sending an `Expect: 100-continue` header?

Comment: I don't believe so. I will update my question with what my request looks like.

Comment: You have to disable the Expect header if you don't want it. See the linked SO answer.

Comment: As far as I know the PHP client implementation hasn't changed and as you can see from my code, I'm not sending a "Expect: 100-continue" header. Before the 29th, the response was a 200 OK and it is only after the 29th that this started happening. No code change to this particular module happened.

Comment: Your PHP code *is* sending the Expect header, because the PHP curl client sends it by default. Server-side support for the Expect header was recently added, which is why you're seeing it. If you want the old behavior back, modify your code to send a blank Expect header, for which an example is listed in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a feature of HTTP 1.1;

Basically, your client sends the *header only* with an extra line;

```
Expect: 100-continue
```

...and waits with posting the body for a few hundred milliseconds. If the timeout expires or there is a `100 Continue` response from the server, the client proceeds with the upload, if there's a `417 Expectation Failed`, the upload is aborted.

That allows the server to check if it will accept the request before the upload. For example if the size of a file is greater than the remaining quota of Google Cloud Storage, it would be useless to upload it before getting refused.

When the upload is complete, you will get an additional `200 OK` response as usual.

EDIT:

I see you're running PHP. More about this in PHP/Curl is available in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359276/php-curl-exec-returns-both-http-1-1-100-continue-and-http-1-1-200-ok-separated-b).

Comment: If I'm not sending an "Expect: 100-continue" header in my request and still getting a "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue" as a response, does this mean there's a bug in the web-service?

Comment: @timberspine CURL seems to do that all by itself according to the linked PHP question. There's a way to disable it there by setting an empty `Expect:` header.

Comment: Just tested this and the empty Expect header solution works great. Thanks again Joachim and jterrace!